# How do before= and after= work in enumitem?

Tags: enumitem

I've tried to define a new description environment for quotations from Wittgenstein's Tractatus, indented on both sides and single space. The main text is one and half space:

```
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{tlpquote}{description}{1}
\setlist[tlpquote]{font=\normalfont,parsep=6pt,itemsep=6pt,topsep=6pt,align=left,labelindent=27pt,labelwidth=36pt,labelsep*=11pt,leftmargin=!,rightmargin=27pt,before=\singlespacing,after=\onehalfspacing}
```

However, the result seems to make the normal paragraph after the quotation single spaced. Moreover, if I have only one item in the list, it's one and half spaced, not single spaced.

I use the following to make the quote environment single spaced (I found this on sx.xs):

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}\begin{spacing}{1}\oldquote}
{\oldendquote\end{spacing}\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}}
```

and this works just fine. I figure I don't understand the before= and after= options of enumitem. (Of course, there's actually very little about enumitem that I *do* actually understand, as opposed to being able to make work, mostly with the help of answers here :-)

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{extbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\pagestyle{plain}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{tlpquote}{description}{1}

\setlist[tlpquote]{font=\normalfont,parsep=6pt,itemsep=6pt,topsep=6pt,align=left,labelindent=27pt,labelwidth=36pt,labelsep*=11pt,leftmargin=!,rightmargin=27pt,before=\singlespacing,after=\onehalfspacing}

% single space in quotes
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}\begin{spacing}{1}\oldquote}
{\oldendquote\end{spacing}\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight

\setlength{\parindent}{18pt}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1cm\indent}}

\begin{document}

The puzzles mount up when Wittgenstein brings in the notions of use,
projection, and sense to characterize propositional signs and propositions:

\begin{tlpquote}
\item [{3.11}] We use the sense-perceptible sign (sound or written sign,
etc.) of the proposition as a projection of the possible situation.


The method of projection is the thinking of the sense of the proposition.

\item [{3.12}] {[}T{]}he proposition is the propositional sign in its \emph{projective
relation} to the world.
\item [{3.13}] To the proposition belongs everything which belongs to the
projection, but not what is projected.

In the proposition, therefore, its \emph{sense is not yet contained},
but the possibility of expressing it.

\end{tlpquote}

\noindent Answering these questions is complicated by the fact that in the \emph{Tractatus}
there are a number of further characterizations of the notion of sense.
As we saw in the last section there is a notion of sense of pictures
as a possible situation. It's clear that this holds for propositions
as well:
\begin{tlpquote}
\item [{4.031(2)}] One can say, instead of, This proposition has such and
such a sense, This proposition presents such and such a situation.
\end{tlpquote}

In addition, A propositional sign is a fact, some determinate way in which its
constituent parts are connected. Such a fact, however, is not a picture
until it is used to project a possible state of things. Projecting
is the same as presenting.

\begin{tlpquote}
\item [{4.022}] The proposition \emph{shows} its sense.


The proposition shows how things stand, if it is true. And it says,
that they do so stand.
\end{tlpquote}


In my view these remarks don't, in the end, point to a single notion
of proposition. However, they do yield two closely connected and mutually
consistent notions.

\begin{quote}A propositional sign is a fact, some determinate way in which its
constituent parts are connected. Such a fact, however, is not a picture
until it is used to project a possible state of things. Projecting
is the same as presenting.\end{quote}

\noindent First, it involves taking the sign-fact to be the realization of a
possible way in which the constituents of the fact are connected---the
realization of logical form---that is also a possible way in which
objects can be connected. This factor is what the ``logical part
of the symbol'' or the ``form of a proposition'' from the \emph{NB}
theory becomes when form is reconceived as possibility of structure.
From this factor we also can see what it means for a picture to ``contain
a possibility'': a (fact used as a) picture is (a fact treated as)
the realization of a possibility.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tlpquote}{\singlespacing} 
\AfterEndEnvironment{tlpquote}{\onehalfspacing}
```

You also need to start your `tlpquote` in a new paragraph: otherwise, you'll mess up the spacing. (The same paragraph can't [easily] be both single and not-single spaced.) The paragraph starting with `\noindent` should therefore be separated from the following `tlpquote`.

PS. I use `enumitem` all the time, but still need to look everything up....

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the missing empty line between one paragraph and the following tlpquote. The `before` code is really before the environment, and so also before any `par` from the list code. `before=xxx` would print the text at the end of the preceding paragraph. `\singlespacing` affects a whole paragraph and when it is issued at the end of a paragraph it will "fight backward". So you should make sure that the paragraph is ended by adding `\endgraf` before `\singlespacing`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{tlpquote}{description}{1}

\setlist[tlpquote]{before=\endgraf\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
The puzzles mount up when Wittgenstein brings in the notions of use,
projection, and sense to characterize propositional signs and propositions:
\begin{tlpquote}
\item [{3.11}] We use the sense-perceptible sign (sound or written sign,
etc.) of the proposition as a projection of the possible situation.
\end{tlpquote}
The puzzles mount up when Wittgenstein brings in the notions of use,
projection, and sense to characterize propositional signs and propositions:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found that \endgraf has to be added to after= as well, otherwise subsequent tlpquote environments appear in onehalfspacing.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is. I had been using both before= and after=. So in your MWE I added after=\onehalfspacing, which produced the effect mentioned. So I modified to after=\endgraf\onehalfspacing, which fixed it; but then I noticed that by deleting after= the effect also vanished. So everything works, but I'd be curious to know why. Thanks!

Comment: `after` is inserted at the end of the last item (try `after=xxx`), so it has like `before` a "backward" effect. But it is unnecessary as the grouping ends the singlespacing anyway.